# value ~ is not a member of slick.lifted.Rep[Option[Int]]

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I have a Scala compile error I have been unable to find any information for. I am using slick 3.0 and am getting a compile error of

`value ~ is not a member of slick.lifted.Rep[Option[Int]]`

I believe the issue relates to the way I am using an Option to represent my ID field.

I have tried adding `id.?` to the id field as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13357067/describing-optional-fields-in-slick) but I still get a compilation error in the same vein. Has anything change in slick 3.0?

My code is as follows:

```
import slick.driver.H2Driver.api._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

case class Recipe(id: Option[Int] = None, name: String, instructions: String, ingredients: String)

object AddFixtures {

  class Recipes(tag: Tag) extends Table[Recipe](tag, "recipe") {
    def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def name = column[String]("name")
    def instructions = column[String]("instructions")
    def ingredients = column[String]("ingredients")

    def * = id ~ name ~ instructions ~ ingredients <> (Recipe, Recipe.unapply _)
  }

  val recipes = TableQuery[Recipes]

  val setup = DBIO.seq(
    recipes.schema.create,
    recipes += Recipe(None, "Chicken with Avocado", "Mix it up", "Chicken, Avocado")
  )

  def apply() = {
    val db = Database.forConfig("h2mem1")

    try db.run(setup)
    finally db.close
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that the problem is that some symbols are not used like before in slick 3.0.0

Take a look [here](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0-M1/upgrade.html) for further problems

in you case the problematic line will be something like this depending what are you going to do, but this should work:

def * = (id, name, instructions, ingredients) <> ((Recipe.apply _).tupled, Recipe.unapply _)

Also you do not need the implicits import

and there is also a problem with your option[Int] parameter: maybe this should be better:

```
import slick.driver.H2Driver.api._


object SlickStackOverflow extends App {

}

case class Recipe(id: Option[Int] = None, name: String, instructions: String, ingredients: String)

object AddFixtures {

  class Recipes(tag: Tag) extends Table[Recipe](tag, "recipe") {
    def id = column[Option[Int]]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def name = column[String]("name")
    def instructions = column[String]("instructions")
    def ingredients = column[String]("ingredients")

    def * = (id, name, instructions, ingredients) <> ((Recipe.apply _).tupled, Recipe.unapply _)
  }

  val recipes = TableQuery[Recipes]

  val setup = DBIO.seq(
    recipes.schema.create,
    recipes += Recipe(None, "Chicken with Avocado", "Mix it up", "Chicken, Avocado")
  )

  def apply() = {
    val db = Database.forConfig("h2mem1")

    try db.run(setup)
    finally db.close
  }
}
```

Or adding .? to the field id, whithout using Option, like we talk in comments, I think that this aproach is better

```
package org.example

import slick.driver.H2Driver.api._

object SlickStackOverflow extends App {

}

case class Recipe(id: Option[Int], name: String, instructions: String, ingredients: String)

object AddFixtures {

  class Recipes(tag: Tag) extends Table[Recipe](tag, "recipe") {
    def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def name = column[String]("name")
    def instructions = column[String]("instructions")
    def ingredients = column[String]("ingredients")

    def * = (id.?, name, instructions, ingredients) <> ((Recipe.apply _).tupled, Recipe.unapply _)
  }

  val recipes = TableQuery[Recipes]

  val setup = DBIO.seq(
    recipes.schema.create,
    recipes += Recipe(None, "Chicken with Avocado", "Mix it up", "Chicken, Avocado")
  )

  def apply() = {
    val db = Database.forConfig("h2mem1")

    try db.run(setup)
    finally db.close
  }
}
```

Comment: Try the new code, I tested and this compile, there is also a problem with Option, I'm not sure if you really need this

Comment: Changing that line and adding Option[Int] to the id column OR adding .? to the id field and not adding Option works.

Comment: Thanks, I also added the third option to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The `field1 ~ field2` construct is actually constructing a `(field1, field2)` tuple under the hood, so as @anquegi points out, simply changing your `*` projection to use a tuple directly will work.

Alternatively, if you want to use `~` to construct the tuple you can get it back by importing [`TupleMethods`](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/api/#slick.util.TupleMethods$) (as `~` [was moved out of the normal import scope](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.0/migration.html#table-descriptions) in Slick 2.0.):

```
import slick.util.TupleMethods._
```

See also: [Slick 2.0 - update two or more columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24174839/135978)

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for that import :)